# Partially locked out after updating to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I am just starting out with Ubuntu after a friend of mine suggested I put my CD collection on an Ubuntu server.
16.04 worked like a charm.

Upgraded to 18.04
Update OK
Login OK
Turn away from the screen, which goes to sleep. On wakeup, password not working.

Hard reboot and password work again.

The music server is working, so I can leave the machine running for days anyway...And then, suddenly, I can wake the screen and log in again.
Then it sleeps, and I can't log in.
Then, after just keeping the thing on for days, I can suddenly log in. And then, I can't. Same password entered, I use "copy/paste"

I see two problems here.
1. I can't log in after waking the screen
2. I suddenly can, until I can't again - without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your password using `passwd`. Maybe after a re-initialization of your password, login after 1 minute vs login after a couple of days are synchronized again.

I am not sure on what might be the root of this issue, though.

Comment: Didn't work
Tried it, and it seemed to work - but now I am back to not being able to log in.
But it was a good suggestion - and it shows the problem lies elswhere.

JO